# What should be the precise coordinates in basemap() for Europe?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, geospatial, spatial, matplotlib-basemap

I am plotting some data on basemap. I am using following line of code to draw a basemap.

```
    m = Basemap(projection='aeqd', lon_0 = 10, lat_0 = 50)
```

But it produces a whole globe. I want to focus on the continent Europe. What should be the precise coordinates for upperrightLatitude, upperrightLongitude etc?

Comment: I would start with some 30 degrees in each direction and see what comes out.

Comment: Thanks, Could you estimate the height & width value? I think these 2 parameters give you a proper image